# Is this sentence an acceptable idiom? "Is there any park near here?"

Tags: grammar, nouns, any

I know that we can use "any" with singular nouns, but there needs to be a proper context as well, such as "Any park needs a playground for kids, I believe".

But what about the following:

> "Is there any park near here?"

Is this a sentence that would make sense or be used by a native speaker in their daily conversation? My understanding is that plural forms would be more grammatically correct. Eg:

> Are there any parks near here?

Therefore, can we say it is one of the common mistakes made by native English speakers? Or is it rather that it's a matter of spoken English which doesn't follow strict grammar rules?

Comment: I don't think we are understanding this question. Yes,it is perfectly good to use "any" with a noun, and the noun is either singular or plural depending on what the rest of the sentence requires.

Comment: To me it seems to involve the count-versus-noncount distinction: *Is there any water around here?* sounds much more natural than does your *Is there any park around here?* Furthermore, ***Are*** *there any parks around here?* sounds fine too. But the *around here* also seems to contribute to your sentence’s sounding awkward because *Is there  any park that has a larger playground?* sounds fine to me.

Comment: Is there a park around here?

Comment: Or . . . "Are there any parks around/near here?"  and also "A park needs a playground for kids, I believe" or "Parks need a playground for kids, I believe."

Comment: And I don't uderstand when you say my question is not understandable. Ok, let's review the grammar rules here. The standard way of sayhing such sentence are these:  Is there [a] park near here? or [Are] there [any] parks near hear?

Comment: Yes, it's OK only in an appropriate context.

Comment: The question isn't clear because it asks more than one question: *"Any park needs a playground for kids I believe". But is this sentence correct?* And this question "would any native probably use it in their daily conversation?" is unclear: use *which* sentence? And why is *probably* in there to further confuse the question?

Answer (score 0):

The Cambridge dictionary addresses your question here: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/any

To summarise, it is a mistake to use "weak form any" with singular *countable* nouns. In your example "park" is a singular countable noun. You should either reword the sentence with plural forms or replace "any" with "a".

As seems partly to be suggested by the comments on your question, this probably isn't something native speakers think consciously about. I don't believe many people would say "is there any park near here", but at the same time in rapid spoken speech most people would not pick up on it if they heard it. So to answer your supplementary questions, no I don't think it's common, except as a slip of the tongue, and it's not "common spoken English that doesn't follow strict rules".

Comment: Thank you. I expected this answer. Just wanted to make sure. I appreciate everybody's help, but still I don't like my question got a dislike hit. How difficult it is to ask something on this fourm.

Comment: I agree people can be a little too eager to downvote/vote to close sometimes. It's partly because a lot of questions give the impression the questioner "isn't trying" and just wants somebody else to do their homework. This wasn't the case with your question, but it was worded a little bit like a request to proofread ("is this correct"). See how I edited and formatted your question to avoid giving that impression. Correct formatting, punctuation, spelling, etc, really helps, even if some grammatical mistakes are inevitable on a learners' site.